# Object matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

i have a problem:

```
DoesNotExist at /products//

Product matching query does not exist.

Request Method: GET

Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:

Product matching query does not exist.

Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 366
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
```

vews.py

```
def SpecificProduct(request, productslug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=productslug)
    context = {'product': product}
    return render_to_response('singleproduct.html',
                           context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

singleproduct.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div id = "singleproduct">
        <p>Name: {{ product }}</p>
        <p>Description: {{ product.en_description }}</p>
        <p>Description: {{ product.sp_description }}</p>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
(r'^products/(?P<productslug>.*)/$', 'zakai.views.SpecificProduct'),
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    en_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sp_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)
    en_description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Describe product in english")
    sp_description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Describe product in spanish")
    photo = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to="product_pic", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.en_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are visiting the URL `/products//` so there is no value for the parameter `productslug` in the URL. That means your `Product` query fails:

```
product = Product.objects.get(slug=productslug)
```

because it has no (correct) value for `productslug`. To fix it, change your URL pattern to:

```
(r'^products/(?P<productslug>.+)/$', 'zakai.views.SpecificProduct'),
```

which requires at least one character for the `productslug` parameter. To improve it furhter you can use the following regex which only accepts `-` and characters (which is what a slug consists of):

```
(r'^products/(?P<productslug>[-\w]+)/$', 'zakai.views.SpecificProduct'),
```

Comment: When i change URL to                                    (r'^products/(?P<productslug>[-\w]+)/$', 'zakai.views.SpecificProduct'),                                           i have      
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/products//

Using the URLconf defined in zakailtd.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^$
    ^products/$
    ^products/(?P<productslug>[-\w]+)/$
    ^admin/

The current URL, products//, didn't match any of these.

Comment: @wadadaaa: That's because there is no slug in the URL `products//`. Fix that URL by adding a slug as well and then see what happens.

Comment: also I can't do auto-complete a slug. This may cause?

Comment: @wadadaaa: I don't know what you're suggesting: if you have a `Product` object with a slug then you should be able to fill the slug into the URL.